# Batch to find a unique word and Copy 100 Lines to a Text File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Large text file Millions of lines.

I wold like to search for a [unique word] and copy 30 lines before and 100 lines after the [unique word] and output the lines to another file.

preferably named as the [unique word].txt

I found this but there is no search in it.

```
DOS Batch To Copy First 100 Lines Of A Text File<<<

@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /P maxlines=Enter number of lines to be moved to new txt document: 
SET /A linecount=0

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (textfile1.txt) DO ( 
  IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop
 ECHO %%A >> C:\users\username\desktop\textfile2.txt
 SET /A linecount+=1
)

:ExitLoop
ECHO All Done.
ECHO.
ECHO Press any key to close this window.
PAUSE>NUL
EXIT
```

to give an example i want

2 line before the unique word and 3 lines after the unique word to be put in a new_file.txt

sorce_file.txt has this content

```
world 1
world 2
world 3
world 4
world 5
unique word
world 6
world 7
world 8
world 9
world 10
```

i run the script and the output new_file.txt has this

```
world 4
world 5
unique word
world 6
world 7
world 8
```

Comment: Where does [unique word] comes from? From user input? From file? Only one unique word per file?

Comment: i have a list of unique words , i can edit the script to search for it. or if the script ask for input .


Only one unique word per file? yes

Comment: Your question title and your description do not match, so please clarify by [edit]ing your post! May this [unique word] occur multiple times in the text file? if so, what to do then?

Comment: IMO write some code in a real language that's a lot of text

Comment: i have one unique word per file . i need the 100 lines after and the 30 line before the word. if that is possible.   thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerShell one liner using the `Select-String` cmdlet with it's `-Context` parameter,
wrapped in batch:

```
powershell -NoP -C "Select-String -Path .\Source_File.txt -Pattern 'unique word' -Context 30,100|ForEach-Object{$_.Context.PreContext;$_.Line;$_.Context.PostContext}|Set-Content New_File.txt"
```

Should be faster than pure batch.

Sample output with `-Context 2,3`

```
> Get-Content .\New_File.txt
world 4
world 5
unique word
world 6
world 7
world 8
```

Comment: uh - that's fast! (besides the time, PowerShell needs to load - much faster the second time, when PowerShell is already in the cache)

Comment: is there a way run this command  with multiple unique words. 'unique word1' & 'unique word2' & 'unique word3'  . or should i run this command several times?

Comment: is their a way to -Append the result to existing file? .

Comment: To append to a file use `Add-Content` instead of `Set-Content`. As pattern is Regular Expression based, you can use an alternation `-Pattern 'unique word1|unique word2|unique word3'`

Answer (score 1):

Using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression command line text processing utility](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044):

```
jrepl "UniqueWord" "" /L /K 30:100 /F "input.txt" /O "UniqueWord.txt"
```

Or to ignore words where UniqueWord is embedded within a larger word:

```
jrepl "\bUniqueWord\b" "" /K 30:100 /F "input.txt" /O "UniqueWord.txt"
```

Use `jrepl /?help` to get a listing of all available documentation within the script.

JREPL is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward, without any need for a 3rd party exe.

JREPL is much faster than any "pure" native batch solution. Not nearly as fast as a compiled executable like grep though.

Comment: I already had a feeling you would come around with `jrepl.bat` sooner or later `:D`

Answer (score 0):

What about change like this ?
ECHO %%A | find "yourWord" >> outputFile.txt

Unless you want more sophisticated search using Cygwin or PowerShell ?
But it could be quite slow to iterate file lines using batch script, maybe short C# code compiled by CSC would perform way better...
Let me know if you want it.

My test batch looks like this now, but unless you filter before processing count works on source lines and not on result (some may be empty).

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del textfile2.txt

SET /A maxlines=10
SET /P maxlines=Enter number of lines to be moved to new txt document: 

SET /A linecount=0

FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (x.txt) DO (
 IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop
 SET /A linecount+=1
 ECHO %%A | find ";" >> textfile2.txt
)

:ExitLoop
ECHO All Done.
```

In case, C# version may look like for example (suppose a bit more readable comparing to batch scripts):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace BatchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String inFile = args[0], outFile = args[1], word = args[2], line;
            int nextLines = 100;

            Queue<String> qt = new Queue<String>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inFile))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outFile))
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                qt.Enqueue(line);
                if (line.Contains(word))
                {
                    foreach (var el in qt)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(el);
                    }
                    qt.Clear();
                    int i = nextLines;
                    while ((i-- > 0) && (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(word)) i = nextLines;
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                } else if (qt.Count > 29) qt.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And compile batch file like this published on my GitHub in [eltomjan\ETEhomeTools\CSharp\Compile.bat](https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/CSharp/Compile.bat)
Inspiration for this search found somewhere here probably:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set LIBS=
for %%x in (*.dll) do (
  echo %%x|findstr ",">nul 2>&1
  if errorlevel 1 (set LIBS=!LIBS!,%%x) else (set LIBS=!LIBS!,"%%x")
)
if "%LIBS%"=="" (for /F %%v in ('dir /s %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\csc.exe /B') do echo %%v -debug %%* > cscLatest.bat ) else (for /F %%v in ('dir /s %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\csc.exe /B') do echo %%v -debug /r:%LIBS:~1% %%* > cscLatest.bat )
if "%1" == "" cscLatest.bat *.cs
cscLatest.bat %*
```

If you do not want to search for some CSC version in windows folders.

Comment: Command line parameters are source SPACE destination file SPACE "text to be found in a line".

Answer (score 0):

look for the line number of your unique word, do some arithmetic to calculate start line and end line. Then output the lines between. The following code even keeps empty lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "file=yourfile.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "[unique word]" "%file%"') do set line=%%a
set /a startline=line-30
set /a endline=line+100
if %startline% lss 1 (set "skip=") else (set "skip=skip=%startline%")

set /a count=startline
for /f "%skip% tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
  if !count! geq %endline% goto :done
  echo(%%b 
  set /a count+=1
)
:done
```

Just don't expect it to be fast... On my system it takes about 10 seconds for a file with 11500 lines